# is there any problem using extended class?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.sail.back.user.model.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
```

i am facing this issue.. can anybody help?

this is my user repository

```
package com.sail.back.user.model.repository;

import com.sail.back.user.model.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

and this is my User  class

```
  

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "nickname")
    private String nickname;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "create_at", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime createAt;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthProvider provider;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserStatus status;

    @Column(name="profile_img_url")
    private String profileImgUrl;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserGender gender;

    @Column(name = "birthdate_year")
    private String birthdateYear;

    @Column(name = "birthdate_month")
    private String birthdateMonth;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(() -> role.name());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    //밴유저
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    //비밀번호
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        if(status == UserStatus.INACTIVE){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static User of(OAuth2User oAuth2User){
        Map<String, Object> map = oAuth2User.getAttributes();
        User user = new User();
        String email =(String) map.get("email");
        String name =(String) map.get("name");
        String nickName =(String) map.get("nickName");
        String birthDateMonth =(String) map.get("birthDateMonth");
        String birthDateYear =(String) map.get("birthDateYear");
        String gender = (String) map.get("gender");
        String picture =(String) map.get("picture");
        AuthProvider provider = (AuthProvider) map.get("provider");

        if (email!=null) user.setEmail(email);
        if (name!=null) user.setName(name);
        if (nickName!=null) user.setNickname(nickName);
        if (birthDateMonth!=null) user.setBirthdateMonth(birthDateMonth);
        if (birthDateYear!=null) user.setBirthdateYear(birthDateYear);
        if (gender!=null) user.setGender(ToMap(gender));
        if (picture!=null) user.setProfileImgUrl(picture);
        if (provider!=null) user.setProvider(provider);
        user.setStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
        user.setRole(UserRole.USER);
        return user;
    }

    static UserGender ToMap(String gender){
        if (gender.equals("male")||gender.equals("MALE")||gender.equals("M")){
            return UserGender.MALE;
        }
        return UserGender.FEMALE;
    }
}
```

this isn't about my gradle.build because i already tested it.

i am assuming about  issue with inheritance because i added customer and consultant class extends User class ..

consultant class

```
  
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "consultants")
public class Consultant {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    private int cost;
    private int reviewCount;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "consultant", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Consulting> consultings = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

customer class

```
 

@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends BaseTimeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Consulting> consultings = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer" )
    private List<Consulting> reservations = new ArrayList<>();


//    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
//    private List<CustomerCommunity> participant=new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    private List<Community> host=new ArrayList<>();


}
```

Comment: What you've shown doesn't match your comments: Customer extends BaseTimeEntity not user. The error itself is indicating a problem because it couldn't find/create the persistence context. I wouldn't guess at why as there could be multiple reasons; the logs should show you error messages around what exactly is going wrong in the persistence unit or other problems. Maybe revert the  changes from when it was last working and compare the startup logs to catch what it might be complaining about

Answer (score 0):

I think u need this article [Hibernate Inheritance Mapping](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)
if I understand it right `User` must be annotated `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)`. It also looks like ids will be duplicated;

Comment: i also have done that too but still same error sir..

Comment: @junwon9824 I see, I created sample project here: https://github.com/jankocev/test
I was wrong, u are looking for @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).